# Did Prince Imrahil try to talk Faramir out of attempting to reconquer Osgiliath?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-return-of-the-king

Prince Imrahil is Faramir's uncle. When Faramir rides to reconquer Osgiliath, Imrahil can be seen among the soldiers in a ring of Minas Tirith. From this I conclude that Imrahil was rather opposed to Steward Denethor's idea that Faramir attempts to reconquer the city. Did Imrahil talk to his nephew about it? If no, why not? Or wasn't he opposed to the idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## As far as we can tell, no

Before Faramir rode of to Osgiliath Denethor held a Council which Imrahil and Faramir were apart of:

> Early in the morning the Council had been summoned. There all the captains judged that because of the threat in the South their force was too weak to make any stroke of war on their own part, unless perchance the Riders of Rohan yet should come. **Meanwhile they must man the walls and wait**.

#### It's important to note that Denethor (as Steward) fundamentally had the same military authority as a King, and held supreme command of the armies of Gondor

The discussion favored towards the Gondorians withstanding a siege within their walls rather than taking the fight to Mordor in their fields - solely because they were to weak to go on the offensive without the Rohirrim.

However Lord Denethor had other plans, and felt that it would be useful to man the outer defenses instead of just the city itself. In this he would be referring to defenses in Osgiliath and the [Rammas Echor](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Rammas_Echor), the outer wall of Minas Tirith.

> 'Yet,' said Denethor, 'we should not lightly abandon the outer defences, the Rammas made with so great a labour. And the Enemy must pay dearly for the crossing of the River. That he cannot do, in force to assail the City, either north of Cair Andros because of the marshes, or southwards towards Lebennin because of the breadth of the River, that needs many boats. It is at Osgiliath that he will put his weight, as before when Boromir denied him the passage.'

Clearly his opinion was final, even after Faramir and Imrahil try to reason with him. In this we see that Imrahil was against them sending out forces, however he did try to weigh the pros and cons to give Denethor a neutral answer:

> 'And what of Cair Andros?' said the Prince. 'That, too, must be held, if Osgiliath is defended. Let us not forget the danger on our left. The Rohirrim may come, and they may not. But Faramir has told us of great strength drawing ever to the Black Gate. **More than one host may issue from it, and strike for more than one passage.**'

Imrahil took the intel of Faramir seriously, and did not think it was wise to spread thin their already diminished forces (keep in mind that many men were held up in Southern Gondor by the Corsairs before Aragorn came to help them).

**To summarise, no, Imrahil did not directly oppose Denethor's will. He *may* have talked to his nephew off-screen later on, but we are not shown this conversation. Ultimately the final command came from Denethor and none of the captains (including his own son) were in any position to refuse him.**

> 'Much must be risked in war,' said Denethor. 'Cair Andros is manned, and no more can be sent so far. But I will not yield the River and the Pelennor unfought – not if there is a captain here who has still the courage to do his lord's will.'

> <sub>All Sources from *The Lord of the Rings, The Return of the King*: Chapter 4, The Siege of Gondor</sub>

Comment: I'd like to point out that this scene played out much differently in the books. PJ butchered it by making it seem Faramir's assault was utterly useless and lasted only less than an hour (though we did get to hear Billy Boyd sing). Whereas in actual fact Faramir's company was busy gathering intel and keeping the orcs back for at least a day before he was finally shot by a Southron dart and saved by Imrahil and Gandalf. Denethor was no idiot and was also using the palantir, so he made the best decision (in his opinion) with what resources he had to help preserve Gondor a little longer.

Comment: Jackson's character assassination of Denethor and, to a lesser extent, Faramir, is one of my major annoyances with his reimagining of LOTR.